# Integer extends Number

Tags: java, collections

Now in this code where I can obviously iterate through the list as `Integers` and `Double` are both *extended* from `Number` super class is working perfectly as intended:

```
public static void viewList(List<? extends Number> num) {
    for (Number num1 : num) {
        System.out.println(num1);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> arl = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    viewList(arl);

}
```

but here to add the data into the collection instead  would never work as Integer and Double are not Superclass of Number and

I understand the PECS concept (Producer Extends Consumer Super)

```
public static void addList(List<? super Number> num) {
    num.add(1);
    num.add(2);
    num.add(3);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> arl = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    addList(arl);

}
```

As expected I am getting an error here, so how to do it in the right way So I will be able to add whatever type I want in the collection?

Comment: You overload the method for each `Number` sub type you want.

Comment: Yep that is what I have already done but is there any more efficient less-coded method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `List<? super Number>` means a list of Number, or of a type that is *above* Number in the inheritance tree. So

- `List<Number>` qualifies: you may add any type of Number to a `List<Number>`
- `List<Serializable>` qualifies: you may add any type of Number to a `List<Serializable>`
- `List<Object>` qualifies: you may add any type of Number to a `List<Object>`
- `List<Integer>` does NOT qualify: you may NOT add any type of Number to a `List<Integer>`

Comment: So there is no any other solution except overloading the types I want to use ?

Comment: You didn't really explain what you were trying to achieve. Maybe your method should be generic: `public static <T extends Number> void addList(List<T> list, T valueToAddToTheList)`

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is that from my main method I can Have ArrayList<Double> ArrayList<Integer> and be able to use one method to add data to both of them

Comment: Add *which* data? Where would this data come from? Your example writes 3 hard-coded integers to the list. You obviously can't write Integer instances to a List<Double>, since Integer doesn't extend Double.

Comment: more precisely if both Integers and Double are Extended from Number, it means we can create one method lets say AddIntoList(List<Number> data)  { data.add(1); } to add numbers to the collection ArrayList<Integer> ar1; ArrayList<Double> ar2; and then use AddIntoList(ar1), AddIntoList(ar2)  right ? or what am i not getting here ? or "1" is not considered as number here ?

Comment: What you seem to be missing is that `data.add(1);` is a shorter way of saying `data.add(Integer.valueOf(1));`. So you're trying to add an Integer instance to the list. And Integer doesn't extend Double. So you can't add `1`, which is autoboxed to Integer, to a `List<Double>`. You could use `list.add(1.0)` or `list.add(1D)`, which would be a short form of `list.add(Double.valueOf(1.0))`, but then it wouldn't work anymore with a `List<Integer>`, because Double doesn't extend Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should make collection of Objects and use appropriate casting